# Creating a ASP.NET MVC build process that builds, installs and starts a Windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

My file structure is like

```
MyMVCProject
  MyWindowsService
    bin
    obj
    .
    .
  MyMVCProject
    App_Data
    App_Start
    bin
    .
    .
  packages
  MyMVCProject.sln
```

and `MyWindowsService` depends on `MyMVCProject` because I want that when my MVC application starts running it has a background process that interfaces my repositories and data contexts defined in the MVP project.

I made `MyWindowsService` install itself when it builds because I put

cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
installutil.exe "$(SolutionDir)\MyWindowsService\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\MyWindowsService.exe"

in the post-build command line for that project. It seems to work when I build that project by itself because I get output like

```
1>  
1>  Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
1>  See the contents of the log file for the C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe assembly's progress.
1>  The file is located at C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.InstallLog.
1>  Installing assembly 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe'.
1>  Affected parameters are:
1>     logtoconsole = 
1>     logfile = C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.InstallLog
1>     assemblypath = C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe
1>  No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe assembly.
1>  
1>  The Install phase completed successfully, and the Commit phase is beginning.
1>  See the contents of the log file for the C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe assembly's progress.
1>  The file is located at C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.InstallLog.
1>  Committing assembly 'C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe'.
1>  Affected parameters are:
1>     logtoconsole = 
1>     logfile = C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.InstallLog
1>     assemblypath = C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe
1>  No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MyMVCProject\MyWindowsService\bin\Debug\MyWindowsService.exe assembly.
1>  Remove InstallState file because there are no installers.
1>  
1>  The Commit phase completed successfully.
1>
```

I'm then trying to start the service in the `App_Start` of my MVC project like

```
        string serviceExecutablePath = Path.GetFullPath(
            Path.Combine(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                @"..\MyWindowsService",
                "bin",
                isDebugMode ? "Debug" : "Release",
                "MyWindowsService.exe"
            )
        );
        Process.Start(serviceExecutablePath);
```

so that if I build-and-run or build-and-debug the entire solution then the steps should be like

(1) Compile MVC project
(2) Compile Windows Service project (because it depends on (1))
(3) Start MVC app, which in starts starts the service built in (2)

However, when I do so I'm getting the error

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: I've no idea what you're ultimately trying to do with this, but starting a Windows Service from an MVC application does not sound like a direction I'd ever want to take.

Comment: Windows services are not started by running the exe. They're installed (as you've done) and then started/stopped via the services admin tool, or via "net start/stop" command line. They remain a service even when rebooted, and usually restart themselves when the machine is booted, so I don't know why your MVC application would even touch the installation or starting/stopping of a service. It sounds like a dangerous thing to do. The security contexts that each operation should normally run in are different.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Hangfire.io](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire)

Comment: Or if you insist on a service, you might want to look on [Topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf)

Comment: If you enter "NET START myServiceName" (where myServiceName is the name of your service), does it start ?

Comment: @PhillipH What should my directory context by when I enter that command?

Comment: `NET.exe` is usually in the path anyway. But I just searched for it windows 10 and found it in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` and `C:\Windows\System32`. You should consider the advice given here - installation and starting of services should be seperate to your application runtime

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your service isn't installed on the server. The best way to do this if the service is not installed is to create a command line executable (bat file) and install and start it from there.

Then executing that file can be done like this:

```
Process serverSideProcess = new Process();
serverSideProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\pathToTheExe";
serverSideProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "arg1 arg2 ..."; 
serverSideProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
serverSideProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
serverSideProcess.Start();
```

Of course you can do the installation and running from your app but remember it is a web app and usually it is not a best practice to run such things as it requires admin privilege.